# How to center a div

Tags: html, css, web, stylesheet

```
#container {
width: 960px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
height: auto; }

#large_box {
text-align: center;
width: 960px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
height: auto; }

#searchbcid {
position: absolute;
left: 400px;
margin-left: 50px;
top: 280px; }

#createbcid {
position: absolute;
margin-left: 250px;
top: 280px;
left: 550px; }

#loginpos {
position: absolute;
margin-left: 20px;
left: 30px;
top: 280px; }
```

in my html there is a div named `container`. All the other `div`s are placed in within the container.
  Another div ie, `large_box` which contains 3 other `div`'s such as `loginpos`,`searchbcid`,`createbcid`.

But i can't center align the `div` `large_box`.

How can I center align it?

Comment: Please provide your HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

In your css use only 
`margin:0 auto;` 
with some width for div then it will automatically aligned in center of that provided width.

happy coding...

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
#wrapper_div{
width:500px;
height:500px;
}

#inner_div{
width:200px;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper_div">
<div id="inner_div">
Centred content here!
</div>
</div
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

**CSS**

```
div#center{
      width:250px;
      margin:0 auto;
      background-color:yellow;
}

/* To support IE */
div#parent{
      align:center;
}
```

**HTML**

```
    <div id="parent">    
      <div id="center">
        I'm in the middle!
      </div>
    </div>
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/v6e2g/)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your margin to 0 auto, it will horizontally center your element within its container with your specified width.

```
#large_box {
text-align: center;
width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
height: auto; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this css for the div. It will horizontally center.

```
#large_box {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto; 
}
```